# Convergence failure with step-by-step parameter estimates in SAS proc logistic using the OFFSET option

Tags: sas, logistic, convergence

I'm trying to fit a logistic model of the following form:

$$ y \sim \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-\beta_X)} $$

where

$$ \beta_X = a_0 + a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3 + a_4x_4 + a_5x_5 $$

In my case, there is often good reason to first fit to a simpler model of $x_1$ and $x_2$; After that, fix $a_0, a_1$ and $a_2$, and then fit the rest. With PROC LOGISTIC, one can achieve that by doing the following:

```
DATA myData; 
  SET myData;
  restrict = a0 + a1*x1 + a2*x2;
  RUN;

PROC LOGISTIC DESCENDING DATA=myData;
  MODEL y = x3 x4 x5 / LACKFIT NOINT OFFSET=restrict;
  RUN;
```

The trick is to use the OFFSET option. That's all fine. The problem is, one often encounters convergence failures. Below is a typical log from SAS.

```
WARNING: Ridging has failed to improve the loglikelihood. You may want to use a different
         ridging technique (RIDGING= option), or switch to using linesearch to reduce the
         step size (RIDGING=NONE), or specify a new set of initial estimates (INEST=
         option). 

WARNING: The LOGISTIC procedure continues in spite of the above warning. Results shown are
         based on the last maximum likelihood iteration. Validity of the model fit is
         questionable
```

Does anyone have experience with such problems? I'm looking for (1) an understanding of why the issue occurs (2) suggestions on how to get around it. One question comes to mind, does constraining $a_0, a_1, a_2$ change the globally concave property of the maximum likelihood function of the logistic model with respect to the remaining list of parameters: $a_3, a_4, a_5$? If it doesn't, why is there a convergence issue at all?